# Environment variables in Windows makefiles

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw, environment-variables

I have the following in a `makefile` I'm using with `mingw32-make`

```
ifeq (%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%,AMD64)
    ARCH ?= 64
else
    ARCH ?= 32
endif
```

For some reason `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` isn't returning the correct value. I've tried `$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)` and `$(%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%)` as well. Not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: What does `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` return? (in the shell).

Comment: Thats interesting, just echo $(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE) in a makefile returns x86.  don't know why different from just running in cmd shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out and noted in your comments, Windows will set `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` to `x86` for 32-bit applications, even if they are actually running on a 64-bit OS  (for app compatibility purposes, I'd assume).

If you want your makefile to determine what the underlying OS type really is, have it check first for the environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432`, which will tell a 32-bit application the actual OS architecture.

If `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` isn't set, then fallback to checking `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`. Windows only sets `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` if the OS is 64-bit and the process is 32-bit:

```
ifeq ($(PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432),AMD64)
    ARCH ?= 64
endif

ifeq ($(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE),AMD64)
    ARCH ?= 64
else
    ARCH ?= 32
endif

$(info $(ARCH))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the source of this information? What a funny name for a variable...

Comment: @kebs: There's some official documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274.aspx However, they way they document it is at least confusing and is arguably wrong.  I assume the name is based on the Wow6432 terminology MS uses for other aspects of the Wow64 environment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as `make` is involved, the correct syntax for accessing a variable is `$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)`

On Linux, the symbol should be "exported" in order to be accessed with `make` , I can't tell if there is a similar mechanism on Windows.

Alternatively, you can try this syntax:

```
ifeq "$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)" "AMD64"
    ARCH ?= 64
else
    ARCH ?= 32
endif
```

Also, just to check, add this dummy recipe to your makefile:

```
show:
    @echo "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)"
```

and enter `make show` at the shell prompt.

Comment: From what I've found, $(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE) returns not the cpu arch but the arch the application was compiled for, so with 32-bit make, it gives 32. In 64-bit make, it gives 64. This is troublesome because even 64-bit versions of MinGW ship with mingw32-make.

Comment: Can't say, my OS does not have that variable. But does the answer I gave fit ? If yes, could you accept it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not with the makefile itself but with the variable being used. I haven't found a variable that returns the actual operating system's architecture, and this particular one simply returns the architecture make was compiled for, as the variable is being called from make. I've resorted to simply defaulting to 32-bit on Windows.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question, I though it was some makefile syntax trouble.